# Restfuse HttpTest with MULTIPART_FORM_DATA?

Tags: java, rest, junit

```
@HttpTest(method = Method.PUT, path = "/v1/deliveries/" + DELIVERY_ID, headers = { @Header(name = "Accept-Encoding", value = "multipart/form-data") }, content = "{}" type = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA, file="myfile.txt")
public void testUpdateDeliveryDetails()
{
        assertEquals("204 response if Delivery is successfully updated", Status.NO_CONTENT.getStatusCode(), response.getStatus());
}
```

myfile.txt contains multipart form data and I want to load it in this unit test but even if I have that txt file in the class path it is giving me a restfuse error saying ""myfile.txt" is not in the class path. I am using eclipse and can anyone tell me where I should place this file and will restfuse read the contents of this file and how do i declare the file name in the filename property tag?

I get the following error

```
Caused an ERROR
[junit] Could not open file myfile.txt. Maybe it's not on the classpath?
[junit] java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not open file myfile.txt. Maybe it's not on the classpath?
```

Answer (score 0):

Put that file in test resources & provide file path with slash..like
file="/myfile.txt"